# Recommended pixel size for QR code ver 2 -- UX for QR codes

Tags: user-experience, qr-code

For my PC/Mac/Linux website, is there a recommended pixel size for a QR code aimed at people with iPhone/Android phone readers?

I'll be using the QR code ver 2 with Q redundancy. See [ref](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/qr_codes.html).

But what size should I make it in pixels? 100 x 100? Larger? I also saw one site that had a relatively small QR code on the page with a comment that you can click the code to show a popup with a larger version for easier scanning. Is that UX (user experience) needed/recommended?

I've only found blog posts that say "try it out." Any more definitive recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "L" redundancy. The benefit of the simpler code outweighs the lower error correction in practice. At Google, we recommended print advertisers use this with a version 2 code and print no smaller than 0.5" on a side. THe question of resolution is irrelevant for a QR code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Number of pixels matters since pixel count of the qr code image / pixels per inch on the monitor = size of the image in inches on the monitor. I think I'll go with 150 or 200 pixel image. Should then be plenty big for the cameras.

Answer (score 0):

The reason most say 'try it out' is that typically your QR code would be integrated into a website and you want the barcode to look nice in it. I rather like the popup version since some Android devices may have a fixed focus camera and the larger a QR code is, the better/easier it is to scan for those devices. Of course too large and it may exceed the scanning area of the device such as a laptop screen, and the user has to pull back to get it in frame.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for a while myself.  We created a QR code creator at http://www.chagrinfallscomputerrepair.com/QRcode.aspx and give the user the option of making it any size in a png file format.  I think the answer is "as big as it will fit".  The problem is the quality of the image I believe.  When printing a QR code, obviously you want to use a quality printer who can print the quality necessary.  Image resolution is key, of course.  The higher the better.  So if you can get the quality up, the image size can come down.  I am working on a better answer than this, but this is what I have for the moment.  Obviously anything you do you should test to be sure it works as expected.